# Can't get a Mule flow-reference to recognize imported resource (external flow) from an external jar

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I cannot get a flow or a sub-flow that is in an external Mule application to display in the *Flow name:* drop-down of the Flow-Reference component of another project (my main project).

I have closely followed the example [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/32X/Sharing+Custom+Configuration+Fragments) from the MuleSoft documentation regarding the sharing of fragments.

It all works as per the tutorial, except I cannot get the external flow/sub-flow's name to appear in the drop-down of the main project's Flow-Reference component.

1. All of the maven stuff is fine.
2. The dependency is properly coded in the main Project's POM.
3. The jar displays in the Referenced Libraries.
4. The jar contains the application file I need (common-mule.xml).
5. If I force an error, by temporarily changing the name of import
   resource, it correctly throws a not-found message.  So, I know the
   classpath is finding this external resource just fine.

BUT... when I double-click my Flow-Reference in the main project, I am not able to see the external flow in the *flow names* drop down.

Am I wrong about how this should work?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

I tried doing the same thing and it is possible using the XML editor. My findings were -

If you are using maven the referenced project must be packaged as a jar and must be available on the referencing project's classpath.

You can refer to these for linking details:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/sharing-custom-code

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.5/sharing-custom-configuration-fragments

After importing the xml as resource, you can simply type in the flow name in `flow-ref` and use it. It will give an error in the studio UI but the project is successfully built and the referenced flow is used as expected at runtime.

Its the bug with Studio UI only.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use import of the flows in jar in your main project.

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:import resource="classpath:source_flow.xml"/>
    <spring:import resource="classpath:global-config.xml"/>
</spring:beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Studio doesn't load elements from configuration files in JARs located on the build-path, so what you're trying to do is impossible (at least, currently).

Comment: Thank you so much at least for clarifying that I'm not crazy.  If the tutorial was a how-to reference flows from an external application, and it leads you through creating a jar along with a Maven dependency snippet, then how Do you reference an external flow from another application?  Is it a matter of just manually updating the main project flow-reference?  I did that al

Comment: Thank you.  So, the documentation suggests a capability that doesn't actually exist?   The notion of shared flows stored in another project is not possible?

Comment: Switch to the XML editor mode: there you can type anything you want in the `flow-ref` element.

Comment: Correct.  You can type anything in you like.  It is an error.  The typed-in flow cannot be found, even at run-time.  Assuming it did work, would you be suggesting that to use a common-flow from another project, it would mean working manually from that point on?  And no longer being able to use the visual designer?

Comment: This is weird, then, maybe a regression? This used to work :(

Comment: No problem.  I believe you've answered my question--It cannot be done.  It's disappointing that the documentation expressly says it's possible, and is even a recommended approach.

Comment: Report the issue here: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE , providing the different config bits from the different JARs, and please share the JIRA link so we can upvote/follow.

Comment: Have you tried to use a VM transport with request-response that in practice will give you the same behavior of flow reference ? This is what I use when I include common components and is working fine even on last Mule version.